# android.os.Build.Version using 4.4.2 only

Tags: android, sdk, android-4.4-kitkat

I have code that works in android version 4.4.3 but not in 4.4.2 and I need it to redirect to a certain page when its using 4.4.2 however I can't seem to find a way of redirecting only for the specific version number the code below redirects when a device is using KitKat but I need it to be edited so that instead of using VERSION_CODES.KITKAT it will be something like VERSION_CODES.4.4.2. is this possible? if so what is the correct syntax.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        String localUrl = "file:///android_asset/splash/splash.html?v=kitkat";

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(localUrl);

}
```

Comment: Try posting the code that's giving you troubles, perhaps there's a way to make it work.

Comment: @Nicklas the code isn't giving any problems I Just need to specify the version of kitkat it's using that will make the if statement work without it taking all versions of kitkat as is currently happening. The code I'm using is above

Comment: To quote question: "I have code that works in android version 4.4.3 but not in 4.4.2" - Try posting that code.

Comment: @Nicklas It's to do with camera access within a webview that there is an issue with kitkat but in the latest release 4.4.3 is works I'm not trying to fix the code I currently have I just want the redirect to work in that if statement if the device is running 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this possible?

There is no `VERSION_CODES` value for 4.4.2, as that is the same API level as the rest of 4.4. You are welcome to attempt to parse the `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` value and see if it is some version that you do not support, as I think that will return something like "4.4.3".

Comment: is this using Build.version.RELEASE because build.RELEASE is showing up that it doesn't exist. Also what is the correct syntax for this i'm not really sure how to do this as i've never had a problem like this before

Comment: @user1984755: Oops, yes, I meant `Build.VERSION.RELEASE`. I will edit the question shortly. There are no syntax rules for `RELEASE`, and so this will be unreliable. Personally, I'd avoid whatever behavior you are encountering that is causing you to care about the patch-level differences.

Answer (score 2):

As @CommonsWare said, your only option is to parse `Build.VERSION.RELEASE`. Here's the code that will do what you need.

```
boolean isSupported = false;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // Android 4.4W and up
        isSupported = true;
    } else {
        // Android 4.4
        String[] parts = Build.VERSION.RELEASE.split("\\.");
        if (parts.length >= 3 && Integer.parseInt(parts[2]) >= 3) {
            // Android 4.4.3 to 4.4W
            isSupported = true;
        }
    }
}

if (isSupported) {
    // Android 4.4.3 and up
} else {
    // Android 4.4.2 and down
}
```

Comment: but better avoid parsing int without a try...catch. And it may also fail on custom rooms :)